# Not able to set ringtone for notification android

Tags: android, notifications

I am developing an application that needs to set ringtone for notification, for that i am using ringtone picker which shows list of ringtone on picker and i am able to select ringtone but again on setting ringtone next time, ringtone picker does not show previously selected ringtone and also notification comes with default ringtone. I got stuck into it and not able to find any solution. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
public class ActivitySettings extends Activity {
    Context mContext;
    // making TypeFace object global for setting custom font to various Views
    Typeface objTypeFace;
    // variables for toggle button values
    boolean notification;
    // declaring toggle button objects
    ToggleButton toggleNotification;
    // Key for Checking whteher notification is on or off
    public static final String PREFS_NOTIFICATION = "Notification";
    Uri uri1,ringtone;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        mContext = this;
        // getting font object
        objTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getBaseContext().getAssets(),
                "fonts/HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md.ttf");
        // getting all textview objects from xml layout
        TextView txtHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Setting_txtHeading);
        txtHeading.setTypeface(objTypeFace);
        TextView txtNotification = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Setting_txtnotification);
        txtNotification.setTypeface(objTypeFace);
        TextView txtTone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Setting_txtsettone);
        txtTone.setTypeface(objTypeFace);
        TextView txtSyncContact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Setting_txtSynContact);
        txtSyncContact.setTypeface(objTypeFace);
        // getting all buttons object from xml layout
        Button btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        toggleNotification = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.Setting_togglenotification);

        // adding click events to various buttons
        btnBack.setOnClickListener(clickButtons);
        txtTone.setOnClickListener(clickButtons);
        toggleNotification.setOnClickListener(clickButtons);
        // getting values of toggle buttons from shared prefrence
        notification = CommonUtility.getNotificationFromPrefernce(mContext,
                PREFS_NOTIFICATION);
    } // on create ends


@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        // setting toggle buttons according to various values
        if (notification) {
            toggleNotification.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            toggleNotification.setChecked(false);
        }

    } // method ends

    // Click Listener for various buttons
    public OnClickListener clickButtons = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.Setting_txtsettone:
                // code for setting notification tones


            Intent tmpIntent = new Intent(
                        RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                tmpIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
                        RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                tmpIntent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, false);
                startActivityForResult(tmpIntent, 123);
                break;
            case R.id.btnBack:
                finish();
                break;
            case R.id.Setting_togglenotification:
                if (toggleNotification.isChecked()) {
                    notification = true;
                    CommonUtility.setNotificationPrefernce(mContext,
                            PREFS_NOTIFICATION, notification);
                } else {
                    notification = false;
                    CommonUtility.setNotificationPrefernce(mContext,
                            PREFS_NOTIFICATION, notification);
                    // Clear all notification
                    NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    nMgr.cancelAll();
                }
                break;

            }
        }
    }; // click events ends


    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && rerequestCode==123) {
            Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);          
            if (uri != null) {
            String ringTonePath = uri.toString();
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(
                    mContext,
                    RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,
                    uri);
            System.out.println("SElected tone uri is ///////"
                    + uri);
        }
    }   

    }

} // final class ends
```

And in logcat i got this error but on Google i am not find any solution of this

```
  03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13090)
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
03-13 19:33:55.189: E/DatabaseUtils(403):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
03-13 19:33:55.319: D/AbsListView(19933): unregisterIRListener() is called
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have not looked through your code, but my first guess would be the logcat output, it tells you pretty much exactly what's wrong. You are missing a required permission:

```
...this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

EDIT: Ok I checked the permission and this is pretty bad. You won't be able to use this permission as it is a signature level permission. You are using something in your code which is of limits to normal developers.

Comment: i had added this permission to my application manifest.xml but it is not working buddy

Comment: Yeah I already noticed and edited my answer, please post more of your logcat output.

Comment: Could you still post more? I need to see where exactly you run into the permission problem and for that I need to see a lot of logcat output before and after the SecurityException.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already fixed that, but for anyone interested - I've had the same issue (that seems to be more common on Samsung devices) and the solution that I've found was to give READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

As a side note: INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL seems to only be possible to work if your application is native, otherwise I